# Git : How can change past commit from master branch to other branch?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I had weak of git knowledge.
I have one brach named 4.4.8. and I want modify 1fxxxx commit on master branch.
Master branch already had other version commit.
I don't know how can merge past commit from master to other branch.

--- Branch structure --

4.4.8 branch -- commit1 (current)
commit2

master branch -- 1fxxxx - merge remote tracking branch origin/4.4.8
---

Comment: Do you want to merge `4.4.8` branch with `master`?

Comment: yes. I don't know which way used.

Comment: In git, commits don't know what branch they're on; instead, branches point at commits, and commits point at their parents. It might be worth finding a general introduction to git, so that you can think about what you need in a clearer way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a `rebase`.

```
git checkout master
git rebase 4.4.8
```

However, if there are any conflicts, you'll have to resolve them at this point. This will not create a merge commit.

OR

You could do `merge`,

```
git checkout master
git merge 4.4.8
```

If there are conflicts, you will have to resolve them. [Here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts) is a good beginner's tutorial for that. A merge commit will be created in case it was not a clean merge.